# Visual Studio Build Error When Using .NET Code in '#Include' Directive

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a number of #include directives in asp.net page that i use to share page snippets (e.g. header, footers, links) between pages.  In some cases I also have some asp.net code in the include file. It works fine in the browser/app and I never have issues, however, whenever I try to build the project in Visual Studio it shows as an error and I can never build.

The reason for the error is obvious. Since that include file doesn't have the ASP.NET declarations, etc... VS thinks that page should not have the asp.net code there, cannot find the associated class, objects, or whatever

How do I get around this?

By the way... I'm old school and from the 'asp' days so I still use includes, but if anyone knows of a more current/official way I should be doing this I'd love to hear it.

Example:

```
'Main Page
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="false" Etc... %>
<script runat="server">
    Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        response.write("hello")
    End Sub
</script>
<html><head></head>
<body>
<div id='header'>
     <!--#include file="myincludefile.aspx"-->
</div>
<div id='content'>
    blah, blah, blah...
</div>
</body>
</html>

'Include file: myincludefile.aspx
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="click me" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Have a look at user controls - should be pretty much exactly what you want. Just create a new user control (ascx) and add it to the pages you want.

Comment: Hm. I've used user controls for other things but never considered to it for my entire header, footer, and navigations.  I guess that is possible of course, but is that a standard approach?  Versus master pages of course which I don't really like to use

Comment: Yep, perfectly fine. It was really the only reasonable method *before* master pages came around - the user control is a part of the page as any other, with all of its own state, events and everything.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for  your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Luann's suggestion, user controls are the way to go to replace includes.

I found a few references for others interested

https://www.mojoportal.com/usercontrols-as-include-files.aspx

http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/10/smart-headers-and-footers-using-asp-net-user-controls/

http://forums.asp.net/t/1421806.aspx?Master+Pages+vs+User+Control+vs+Include+File